# How does wikipedia generates PDF

Tags: pdf, wikipedia

I would like to know on how wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/) creates PDF? It seem to be using some application at the back-end. Could anyone please let me know on how this is done?

Thanks
Srikanth

Comment: Can you give an example of where Wikipedia uses PDFs?  I didn't know that they did this.

Comment: @templatetypedef: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Books

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia runs [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/).
A Google check tells me that they have two PDF extensions.
This one is the one who's still mantained: [PDF_Writer](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPDF_Writer)

It doesn't use a PHP HTML→PDF generator, (though there are some)
It actually does something trickier and more clever.

> The PDF Writer uses the **Python [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/)** libraries to generate PDF based on a
>   DOM derived from parsing mediawiki-markup using the **mwlib parser**.

Comment: One of the clever thing that I have observed is, in case of tables with more columns, it tries to fit in the A4 page by reducing the font-size of the characters contained in the table! I will check out PDF_Writer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

To confirm ZJR's answer, these are the document properties:

[image: Document properties]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really proves on what they use.